# Directives interfering with each other

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 2 directives that are on the same level as follows:

```
function signUpForm(djangoAuth, Validate){
 return{
    restrict:'A',
    controller:["$rootScope","$scope",function($rootScope, $scope){
       $scope.submitFunction = function(formData){
        //do stuff 
      }
    }]
 }}

 function signInForm(djangoAuth, Validate){
 return{
    restrict:'A',
    controller:["$rootScope","$scope",function($rootScope, $scope){
       $scope.submitFunction = function(formData){
        //do stuff 
      }
    }]
 }}
```

My HTML is as follows:

```
<div>
  <div class="email_log_container">
     <form name="signup_form" class="signup_form" sign-up-form
           novalidate ng-submit="submitFunction(signup_form)">

           <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" >

     </form>
  </div>

  <div class="email_log_container">
     <form name="signin_form" class="signin_form" sign-in-form
           novalidate ng-submit="submitFunction(signin_form)">

           <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" >

     </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that when I click the submit button on the second form, it actually submits the first form which results in errors. So I went on to add isolate scopes to the directives, now what happens is that the functions and attributes attached to $scope in the controller are not being picked up now. For example ng-submit does not know about the submitFunction within the controller.

Can anyone help me with ideas on how to stop these two directives from interfering with each other?

Comment: Why do you need a directive here?

Comment: I need each directive to handle each form as my forms are involved in a more complex setup that includes calling a django-restframework API.

Comment: The django-restframework API handling should be solved in a service. There is a need for a directive IMO.

Comment: Okay structure might be up for question but given what I have, how do I get to solve the problem at hand?

Comment: Ok, made it work for you. But you should focus an other solution IMO. Please check my answer.

Comment: You can make use of decorator to extend the inbuilt directive. Go through [custom ng-submit](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24911603/3543808)

Answer (score 0):

While you are using a controller but no template for your directive this will not work. Try it like in this [runnable demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7vooL3a6/) and add the form as a template into your directive. In that way you will be able to handle all the `$scope` goodness in your directive controller itself. The template itself will be compiled and uses the directive controller.

#### View

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div class="email_log_container"> 
    <sign-in-form></sign-in-form>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### AngularJS application

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
});

myApp.directive('signInForm', function signInForm(){
  return{
    restrict:'E',
    replace: true,
    template: '<form name="signin_form" class="signin_form" sign-in-form novalidate ng-submit="submitFunction(signin_form)"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" ></form>',
    controller:["$rootScope","$scope",function($rootScope, $scope){
      $scope.submitFunction = function(formData){
        //do stuff 
        console.log('sdfsdfd');
      }
    }]
}});
```